# Byte Code Manipulation in Android

Tags: java, android

I have a java agent that monitors the performance of Java Applications and it works on the principle that it manipulates the byte code before it gets loaded from the JVM. So now I need this Java Agent to monitor the performance of Android Applications by working in the same principle of manipulating the byte codes. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Are you building your own Android hardware or custom ROM? Or, are you planning on using this on rooted devices? Or, are you planning on doing this bytecode manipulation at compile time?

Comment: Normally there is no JVM on Androids, but the byte code is translated on beforehand.

Comment: I mean to say in Java you have .class generated whose byte code is manipulated by a Java Agent before it gets loaded on JVM. I have been specific to java.lang.instrument package that does the job of monitoring the performance of app. Is there a similar concept in Android where I can manipulate the byte code?

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you are going to do, but since Android 5 the Applications are precompiled once you install them. So there is no actual bytecode anymore - however by lazy-loading classes at runtime yourself it may still be possible to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved this :) I did this using AspectJ for Android :) The same Java agent would not achieve this but using AspectJ you can manipulate byte code or instrument it before conversion to .dex in android. Please follow this link http://ikrk.wz.cz/archiv/23-how-to-use-aspectj-with-android.